# A signaling problem

Tags: logical-deduction

There are garrisons of soldiers spaced equally along the borders of the Empire. When the border is attacked, the nearest garrison lights a fire on a large tripod. The distance between garrisons is such that this signal fire is visible to the neighboring garrisons on either side, but only to those immediately adjacent garrisons.
Every time a garrison sees a signal fire, they will light their own fire as well, passing the alert down the line along the border.

How will the High Command, which is situated along the borders, know where to send reinforcements?

The problem is translated from an Italian book "La bottega dello scienziato" by Lucio Russo and Alessandro Della Corte (Il Mulino, 2016).

Comment: It isn't clear where the High Command is located. As posted, there doesn't seem to be a puzzle: when a signal fire is seen, send reinforcements in that direction.

Comment: The problem Is to send reinforcements in the most effective way

Comment: It is not stated whether high command essentially takes the place of a garrison or if it lies between two neighbouring garrisons.

Comment: You can assume that It lies between two neighbouring garrisons i Guess but It Is not specified in the original problem statement.

Comment: So as soon as one of the garrisons next to high command lights up, the other garrison will also start lighting its fire?

Comment: The sequence of lightning starts from the attacked garrison and It ends when It reaches the High command

Answer (score 1):

The High Command will

> take note of whether it noticed the fire from the garrison clockwise from it or counterclockwise from it along the border. The reinforcements will then go to the garrison where the fire was seen and continue in that direction along the border until they get to the garrison where the signal originated.

Answer (score 0):

The border of the kingdom should have an asymmetric shape for the High Command to find the border location which is  attacked. Since the border is a closed path, when a part of it is attacked both the garrisons close to it will light a fire. Due to the border's irregular shape the two edges of the fire reach the High Command at different times. Choosing the path along which the garrison close to the High Command is lit first will be the shortest route to sent reinforcements.

Comment: Why can you assume that the border is a closed path? For instance, Roman Empire garrisons were only located along the northern border and as such they were not forming a closed path.

Comment: @Lucius Absent a closed path, I'm not sure there's any way to get an answer here. Are you aware of a solution that does *not* assume a closed path?

Comment: No i dont know the solution  if you assign an integer Number to all the garrisons and assume a modulation of the signal of the Fire based on that integer maybe It can work

Comment: @Lucius if you don't know the solution, please post where the puzzle originated. Did you post the exact puzzle description, or did you paraphrase it, so it is "something like" the puzzle you remember?

Comment: I have translated from an italian book the text of the problem